# GPU'S Failed cannot create DAG

Tags: mining, gpu, error, memory, dag

Last night everything is fine and then this morning I check my mining its's closed I think it was restarted or close accidentally then when I open my pool I have this error.

```
ETH: 5 pools are specified
Main Ethereum pool is eth-eu1.nanopool.org:9999
At least 16 GB of Virtual Memory is required for multi-GPU systems
Make sure you defined GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
Be careful with overclocking, use default clocks for first tests
Press "s" for current statistics, "0".."9" to turn on/off cards, "r" to reload pools, "e" or "d" to select current pool
OpenCL initializing...
```

[image]

I already adjust my performance option and restart but nothing happens.

Anyone can help me here? Thankyou

Comment: have the same problem
someone please help virtual already set up to 16GB

Comment: I change mine higher than 16GB i change to 60 and now its working but my hash goes down

Answer (score 1):

Are you on cards with limited on-board RAM, such as 3GB cards? [The DAG size is now 2.48GB](https://investoon.com/tools/dag_size) and it is possible that your cards can no longer hold the DAG in VRAM.

Also, you should set your Windows page file size to be larger to `card_vram_capacity * num_of_cards`. So if you have 6 GPUs with 8GB RAM, set your page file to 48GB at a minimum.

Comment: I have 8 rx580's 8GB

I try to adjust my performance option higher than 16GB i put it 60GB and now I can start mining but the problem is my hash goes down